# appSettings.json not read when launching .net core windows service

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, appsettings

I follow the Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) to build a Windows service.

The `appSettings.json` file is read when running from the Visual Studio or command line, but when the service DLL is executed from the Service Manager, it fails.

All variables populated from config remain empty remain empty.

The problem is that Windows Service Manager set the default directory to `c:\windows\system32`.

How to read from installation path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At service startup, set the working path to the installation path this way:

```
//program.cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration(conf =>
  {
      conf.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
  })
  ...
```

This modification ensures that the working path is set to the installation path, allowing proper access to configuration files when the service is executed from the Service Manager.

Comment: Not working for me.  I am however using   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);    builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(conf =>
                {
                    conf.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                });

Comment: I understand the logic behind this advice, however this does not seem to work for my service. If I ran it as an EXE, it's ok, but it fails to read its conversation if ran as a service. I have tried both in SystemLocal account and a custom account. 
But using "Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);" instead seems to work, but it does not seem to be as clean as conf.SetBasePath.